# Notice: Undefined variable troubleshoot

Tags: php

Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/egnhq/cms.egnhq.com/templatev3.php on line 593

$m_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbrlist WHERE sid = '" . $f_squad . "'");

im new to php, is there an easier way to edit this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.

$m_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbrlist WHERE sid = '" . $f_squad . "'");

suppose to be:
$n_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbrlist WHERE sid = '" . $f_squad . "'");

had it going back to wrong one.